# How to mount azure datadisk in virtual machine

Tags: azure

How can I mount an Azure data disk from a linux virtual machine?

I think it might be something like this

```
az vm disk attach-existing [virtualmachinename] [datadiskname]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, its confusing because the documentation for creating azure disk is hard to sort from the documentation for creating a mount point.  This is the relevant documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk#connect-to-the-linux-vm-to-mount-the-new-disk

For an alternative walkthrough, see this blog: https://chrismckee.co.uk/creating-mounting-new-drives-in-ubuntu-azure/. I couldn't identify the disk I'd like to mount with the official Azure docs and this post helped.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead and the manual still doesn't describe how to figure out which SCSI drive is which disk...

Comment: Maybe this will help a bit, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13958

Comment: yup, `fdisk -l` shows the sizes and `mount -l` can list already mounted drives, so if you don't add multiple drives of the same size at the same time you can usually figure it out with those two commands

Comment: the 2nd link is dead. also google cache cant help. the azure docs link is not useful since when you follow those steps, you end up having the problem from the question.

Comment: @unreal sorry, when you figure it out, post the answer and I'll delete mine.  I haven't done Azure stuff in years

Comment: Here is the link to initialize new data disk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal#initialize-a-new-data-disk

Answer (score 1):

You can attach any disk size with azure virtual machine

https://mocktool.com/2020/11/24/attach-managed-disk-to-azure-linux-virtual-machine

Answer (score 1):

Find the disk
Once connected to your VM, you need to find the disk. In this example, we are using lsblk to list the disks.

`lsblk -o NAME,HCTL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -i "sd"`

The output is similar to the following example:

```
sda     0:0:0:0      30G
├─sda1             29.9G /
├─sda14               4M
└─sda15             106M /boot/efi
sdb     1:0:1:0      14G
└─sdb1               14G /mnt
sdc     3:0:0:0      50G
```

Here, sdc is the disk that we want, because it is 50G. If you aren't sure which disk it is based on size alone, you can go to the VM page in the portal, select Disks, and check the LUN number for the disk under Data disks.

Mount the disk
Now, create a directory to mount the file system using mkdir. The following example creates a directory at /datadrive:

`sudo mkdir /datadrive`

Use mount to then mount the filesystem. The following example mounts the /dev/sdc1 partition to the /datadrive mount point:

`sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadrive`

Answer (score 0):

If you have just created a new Disk and attached it in the Azure UI, follow the below steps in the VM's CLI.

- Create a Filesystem: If the disk doesn't have a filesystem or if it's a new disk, you'll need to create a filesystem on it. For example, to create an ext4 filesystem:

  `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc`
- Mount the Disk: After creating the filesystem, you can proceed to mount the disk as mentioned in the previous response:

  `sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/data`
- Make the Mount Persistent: As previously mentioned, add an entry to the /etc/fstab file to ensure that the disk is mounted automatically after reboots.

  `echo '/dev/sdc /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`